# Use parents document from iFrame to trigger and close window

Tags: javascript, html

I'm practicing using [showmodaldialog.js Polyfill](https://github.com/niutech/showModalDialog) demo.
I add a button in demo-modal.html and try to use button on child window to trigger 'dialog-close' . But I use `window.top.document.getElementById('dialog-close').close();` is not work.
Thanks for help.
The following is my code.

```html
<!-- demo-modal.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <title>showModalDialog modal demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1>showModalDialog modal demo</h1>
      <p>Dialog argments: <span id="arg"></span></p>
      <textarea id="textcontent"></textarea>
      <button id="btn1" onclick="myFunction()">close</button>

      </form>
      <script>
        document.getElementById('arg').innerHTML = window.dialogArguments;
        window.returnValue = "some return value";

        function myFunction(){
          window.top.document.getElementById('dialog-close').close(); //it not work
          //how to use it to close window?
        }

      </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

```html
<!-- demo.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <title>showModalDialog polyfill demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1>showModalDialog polyfill demo</h1>
      <form action="">
        <p>
          <input id="button1" type="button" value="Show Modal Dialog using yield"> <span id="result1"></span>
        </p>
        <p>
          <input id="button2" type="button" value="Show Modal Dialog using async/await"> <span id="result2"></span>
        </p>
        <p>
          <input id="button3" type="button" value="Show Modal Dialog using eval"> <span id="result3"></span>
        </p>
      </form>
      <iframe src="https://ghbtns.com/github-btn.html?user=niutech&amp;repo=showModalDialog&amp;type=watch&amp;count=true" height="30" width="118" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
      <script src="showModalDialog.js"></script>
      <script>
        //using eval
        document.getElementById('button3').addEventListener('click', function() {
          var ret = window.showModalDialog("demo-modal.html", "some argument", "dialogWidth:500px;dialogHeight:200px");
          document.getElementById('result3').innerText = "Returned from modal: " + ret;
        });
      </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem myself!

I change

```
window.top.document.getElementById('dialog-close').close();
```

to

```
window.top.document.getElementById('dialog-close').click();
```

and it works!